# How to use asm code in C++ & Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, assembly

I am doing some cross-platform work, porting code from Linux to Win32, but when it comes to some assembly code, I cannot get it to work.
This code compiles normally in Linux gcc, but will not work in VS2008 --win32.

Some of my code is below. What do I need to do if I want to compile it using VS2008 --win32 platform:

```
static inline void spin_wait(int n)
{
    int    tmp = n;
    while(tmp > 0) { tmp--; asm("" ::: "memory", "cc"); }
}

__asm__ __volatile__(
    "xorq        %%rdx, %%rdx    \n"
    "xorq        %%rax, %%rax    \n"
    "incq        %%rdx        \n"
    "lock cmpxchgq    %%rdx, (%1)    \n"
    "decq        %%rax        \n"
: "=a" (not_set) : "r" (n) : "%rdx");
```

Comment: Brr, the point of spinning is to burn cpu cycles.  The point of writing inline assembly is to not burn cpu cycles.  Use InterlockedCompareExchange().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is about the use of inline assembly, you can still use it in Visual Studio ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f7adz6y.aspx)) although you may need to tweak it for the platform of course.

For example:

```
__asm {
   mov al, 2
   mov dx, 0xD007
   out dx, al
}
```

Comment: but when i debug the porject , it comes some eror,

Comment: @so_and_well: So go ahead and fix the error? Also, you're aware that this example is not a translation of your original code, right?

Comment: yes, i know. you mean ,i should do some job to change asm codes,right?

Answer (score 1):

A thing like "spin_wait" isn't portable, and should be (re)written to what's appropriate for the target platform. It's been a while since I've dealt with the horrible GAS syntax, but xorq means the snippet is for x86-64, right? The Microsoft compilers don't support inline assembly for 64bit targets.

Will [_AcquireSpinLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6950fhbk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) perhaps do the trick?

For larger blocks of assembly (the parts that generally *make sense* to write in assembly), I'd advise you to use an external assembly module with a cross-platform assembler with sane syntax and a good feature set (for instance yasm, fasm or nasm). Of course that's not viable for something as critical and must-be-inline as a spinlock, though :)

Comment: but , i also cann't understand what's the meanning of those asm code ,i just can do nothing, so ,would you help me explain those codes like "lock cmpxchgq   %%rdx, (%1)", what is the result ?  thanks.